# Best practice with MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm just wondering which is the best practice:
I have a table and I want to hide a record so should I use a column like `visible = 1` or should I create another table and transfer the data.

thanks!

Comment: It completely depends on what you're trying to do. Both are possible solutions.

Comment: Hide from where? From output? Then you can filter it out in a query. If you don't need the record anymore, maybe delete it. You should clarify...

Comment: What you're talking about is generally called "soft deletion".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a isHidden field for this purpose. I usually use a tinyint for this.

Answer (score 0):

Tables don't have performance—*queries* have performance. When you're trying to decide how to optimize, concentrate on the queries you will run against the table.

It could be worth moving the data to another table, for example if 90% of the data is "hidden" and rows seldom change their hidden state, you could greatly improve performance for queries against the non-hidden data by keeping that table small.

On the other hand, if you have a mix of queries where you sometimes include and sometimes exclude the "hidden" rows, or rows frequently change their hidden state, it would be more convenient to keep them in the same table.

Both strategies are valid in different circumstances. You need to take all your uses of the data into account.